# How to check if a row exist in an object array?

Tags: powershell

I have an array

```
$a = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "...." -Method Get) | select X,Y,Z # Object[] Z has type of datetime
```

`$a` has `X, Y, Z`.

Now I need to check if a row is in `$a`

```
$x,$y,$z = ....
if ($a -contains $x,$y, $x) { ... } # doesn't work
```

How to do it?

Comment: Try piping the select to `Get-Member` to see what properties are available.

Comment: `$a` has X, Y, Z

Comment: You'll have to share what the data is and what you expect as a return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to test array `$a` for containing an object that has a given set of property values (`$x`, `$y`, `$z`) for a given set of property names (`.X`, `.Y`, `.Z`):

```bsh
$hasObjectWithValues = [bool] $(foreach ($o in $a) {
    if ($o.X -eq $x -and $o.Y -eq $y -and $o.Z -eq $z) {
      $true
      break
    }
  })
```

<sup>Note: The cleaner form `[bool] $hasObjectWithValues = foreach ...` *should* work, but, as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.4, doesn't, due to [this bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10426)</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$a -contains $x,$y, $z`

The RHS of PowerShell's [`-contains` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#containment-operators) only supports a *scalar* (single value), to be tested for equality with the elements in the the array-valued LHS.

However, even if you wrapped your RHS into a single object - `[pscustomobject] @{ X = $x, Y = $y, Z = $z }`, that approach wouldn't work, because `[pscustomobject]`s, as also returned by `Invoke-RestMethod`, are *reference types*, which - in the absence of custom equality comparison behavior - are compared by *reference equality*, meaning that they're only considered equal if they refer to the *very same object in memory*.

Comment: @ca9163d9: My bad - I forgot about [this bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10426), which didn't surface in my informal tests. Please try my update.